# Gazebo simulation, faulty on wheel rotation

Tags: gazebo, simulation, gazebo-model, ros-noetic

[image: My urdf model]

I'm currently linking a model with my cmd_vel. However, I found some faulty on individual wheels, each of wheels dividedly move. like some are rotating in clockwise, some are couter-clockwise, cause an unevenly translation. The URDF file has been attached with this post. I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with my setup?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot
  name="r1-bot">
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="1.575746680995E-05 0 -0.02"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="4.78492035526277" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0164976933926147"
        ixy="1.24313338239843E-18"
        ixz="4.94520401850225E-20"
        iyy="0.0364032483895405"
        iyz="1.41736846507219E-19"
        izz="0.0516216957643921" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="left_front_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.38777878078145E-17 0.00545945945945944 6.93889390390723E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0498455771833578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="1.50954939562691E-05"
        ixy="3.33374489672229E-22"
        ixz="2.74709347018384E-21"
        iyy="2.90148410428802E-05"
        iyz="1.54533657342654E-22"
        izz="1.5095493956269E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/left_front_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/left_front_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="left_front_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.13 -0.111 -0.02"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="left_front_wheel" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 -1 0" />
    <limit
      effort="100"
      velocity="100" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="right_front_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.38777878078145E-17 -0.00545945945945944 2.08166817117217E-17"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0498455771833579" />
      <inertia
        ixx="1.50954939562691E-05"
        ixy="-1.26334324106705E-22"
        ixz="-1.91651516776982E-21"
        iyy="2.90148410428803E-05"
        iyz="-2.78131161921179E-22"
        izz="1.50954939562691E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/right_front_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/right_front_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="right_front_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.13 0.111 -0.02"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="right_front_wheel" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 -1 0" />
    <limit
      effort="100"
      velocity="100" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="left_back_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0.00545945945945944 6.93889390390723E-18"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0498455771833578" />
      <inertia
        ixx="1.50954939562691E-05"
        ixy="6.51878753893785E-22"
        ixz="2.97239867136387E-21"
        iyy="2.90148410428803E-05"
        iyz="1.63428094845551E-22"
        izz="1.50954939562691E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/left_back_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/left_back_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="left_bac_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.12 -0.111 -0.02"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="left_back_wheel" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      effort="100"
      velocity="100" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="right_back_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 -0.00545945945945946 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0498455771833579" />
      <inertia
        ixx="1.50954939562691E-05"
        ixy="4.24025859714313E-22"
        ixz="3.77811760315945E-21"
        iyy="2.90148410428803E-05"
        iyz="1.58030475154248E-22"
        izz="1.50954939562691E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/right_back_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 0.298039215686275 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://r1-bot/meshes/right_back_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="right_back_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.12 0.111 -0.02"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="right_back_wheel" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      effort="100"
      velocity="100" />
  </joint>
 <gazebo>
  <plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    <leftFrontJoint>left_front_joint</leftFrontJoint>
    <rightFrontJoint>right_front_joint</rightFrontJoint>
    <leftRearJoint>left_bac_joint</leftRearJoint>
    <rightRearJoint>right_back_joint</rightRearJoint>
    <wheelSeparation>0.222</wheelSeparation>
    <wheelDiameter>0.070</wheelDiameter>
    <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
    <torque>20</torque>
    <topicName>cmd_vel</topicName>
    <broadcastTF>false</broadcastTF>
  </plugin>
 </gazebo>
</robot>
```